# Retrieve one element 1 time per 10 page reload

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with 10 elements.
$arr = range(0, 9);
I want to retrieve one element one time per 10 page reload.
Ho can I do this?

Comment: Is this what you've been searching for?

Comment: What I'm reading: 1st page load pick a random item and display it, for the next 9 page loads show the same item. For the 11th page load, pick another random item and display it... if so you'll need to store the ID in the users session to keep track of it and how many pages they've viewed since selecting the random item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With session variables and a bit of modular arithmetic, you should get the job done

```
<?php 

session_start();

$array = range(0, 9); // this could be any array
$repeat = 10;

if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
if(!isset($_SESSION['subcounter'])) $_SESSION['subcounter'] = 0;

echo $array[$_SESSION['subcounter'] % sizeof($array)];

if($_SESSION['counter'] % $repeat == 0)
  $_SESSION['subcounter']++;

$_SESSION['counter']++;

?>
```

Use cookies instead of sessions if you want to keep your counter after the browser closes.

**code tested and approved**

Comment: Oh! yes. I can use cookies. That is what I am searching for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = range(0,9);
$random = array_rand($arr, 1);

echo $random;
```

This will pick one element inside the range of your array of `$arr` for every reload.

Answer (score 0):

For you to truly get it to happen once every x times, the server will have to be aware of when the last time it retrieved an element was, as well as how many page refreshes have happened since. You should use a database to retain this info, and reference the DB on each page load to know whether to retrieve an element.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This code will start a user session, and keep count of how many request have been performed, it will then re-generate the array index.

If however you need to slowly exhaust this list, you'll need to keep track of what index's you've assigned to the user, or perform this return incrementally.

```
session_start();

$arr = array('Item A','Item B','Item C','Item D','Item E','Item F','Item A','Item H','Item I','Item J');

if( isset($_SESSION['counter'],$_SESSION['showthisindex']) === false or $_SESSION['counter'] >= 10 )
{
  $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
  $_SESSION['showthisindex'] = array_rand($arr);
}
else
{
  $_SESSION['counter']++;
}

echo $arr[ $_SESSION['showthisindex'] ];
```